# Issues with grffile passing options to graphicx (draft/final)

Tags: graphics, package-options, draft

I’ve been trying to set `draft` mode globally on my document, but I still want `\includegraphics` to work normally, so the `graphicx` package should receive the `final` option.
I’m also using the `grffile` package.

I’ve found that with `grffile`, the `final` option for `graphicx` doesn’t work depending on how exactly the packages are loaded, so only the box with the filename is printed despite setting `final`.
The following is what I’ve found out through experimentation:

```
% result: DRAFT
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{alertmessage-success.png}
\end{document}
```

---

```
% result: DRAFT
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[final]{grffile}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{alertmessage-success.png}
\end{document}
```

---

```
% result: DRAFT
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage[final]{grffile}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{alertmessage-success.png}
\end{document}
```

---

```
% result: DRAFT
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{alertmessage-success.png}
\end{document}
```

---

```
% result: FINAL
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[final]{grffile}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{alertmessage-success.png}
\end{document}
```

---

```
% result: FINAL
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[final]{grffile}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{alertmessage-success.png}
\end{document}
```

So `grffile` must be loaded *first*, *with* the `final` option.
Why is that?
It would be much less error-prone if the whole thing didn’t depend on the order of the packages (how is an average user supposed to figure this out? Especially since `grffile`’s documentation uses examples in the “wrong” [in this case] order:

> ```
> \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}[2006/02/22]
> % \usepackage[latin1]{inputenx}
> \usepackage{graphicx}
> \usepackage[encoding,filenameencoding=utf8]{grffile}
> ```

`grffile` documentation, section 1.4.3).

I assume it has something to do with the fact that `grffile` actually loads `graphics` instead of `graphicx` (there is no mention of the `graphicx` package in `grffile`):

`grffile.sty` v1.17 lines 76–78:

```
\DeclareDefaultOption{%
  \PassOptionsToPackage\CurrentOption{graphics}%
}
```

`grffile.sty` v1.17 line 105:

```
\RequirePackage{graphics}
```

Using TeX Live 2016.